# Lollipop actionbar menu item text is black instead of white?

Tags: android

Here is how I add items to the menu in action bar:

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        TypefaceSpan actionBarTypeFace = new CustomTypefaceSpan("", a.bumpFont);
        SpannableString s = new SpannableString("Done"));
        s.setSpan(actionBarTypeFace, 0, s.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
        MenuItem item = menu.add(21, 142, 0, s);
        item.setTitle(BaseActivity.isLGDevice() ? "Done") : s);
        item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
        // fix android formatted title bug
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2 && item.getTitleCondensed() != null) {
            item.setTitleCondensed("Done"));
        }
    }
```

Item font is usually white, but its black on Lollipop. Anyone know what is the cause of that and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Anyone know what is the cause of that...

Most likely it's caused by the fact the app themes on pre-Lollipop devices and on Lollipop devices have different menu items' text colors.

> ... and how can I fix it?

I've changed the color of menu items' text color in my app in the following way:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/MenuTextAppearance</item>
</style>

<style name="MenuTextAppearance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.IconMenu.Item">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFF</item>
</style>
```

Basically, all you need to do is make your own `MenuTextApperance` style and set it in the app's theme `"android:itemTextAppearance"` element.